# ERROR: tabular dataset treated as image dataset (Vertex AI Pipelines: Custom training)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I used Vertex AI Pipelines to custom train tabular data.

1. I ran the python code below.
2. I CREATE RUN the pipeline with the generated json.
3. The following error occurred at the start of the training.

Why were tabular data sets treated as image data sets? what is wrong?

### Environment

- Python 3.7.3

  - kfp==1.6.2
  - kfp-pipeline-spec==0.1.7
  - kfp-server-api==1.6.0

### Error message

```
ValueError: ImageDataset class can not be used to retrieve dataset resource projects/nnnnnnnnnnnn/locations/us-central1/datasets/3781554739456507904, check the dataset type
    f"{self.__class__.__name__} class can not be used to retrieve "
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/datasets/dataset.py", line 100, in _validate_metadata_schema_uri
    self._validate_metadata_schema_uri()
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/datasets/dataset.py", line 82, in __init__
    return annotation_type(value)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/remote_runner.py", line 176, in cast
    value = cast(value, param_type)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/remote_runner.py", line 205, in prepare_parameters
    prepare_parameters(serialized_args[METHOD_KEY], method, is_init=False)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/remote_runner.py", line 236, in runner
    print(runner(args.cls_name, args.method_name, executor_input, kwargs))
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/remote_runner.py", line 280, in main
    main()
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_cloud_pipeline_components/aiplatform/remote_runner.py", line 284, in <module>
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

### Python code:

```
import datetime
from kfp.v2 import dsl, compiler
from kfp.v2.google.client import AIPlatformClient
import google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform as gcc_ai

PROJECT = "my-project"
PIPELINE_NAME = "test-pipeline"
PIPELINE_ROOT_PATH = f"gs://test-pipeline-20210525/{PIPELINE_NAME}"

@dsl.pipeline(
  name=PIPELINE_NAME,
  pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT_PATH
)
def test_pipeline(
  display_name: str=f"{PIPELINE_NAME}-2021MMDD-nn"
):
  dataset_create_op = gcc_ai.TabularDatasetCreateOp(
    project=PROJECT, display_name=display_name,
    gcs_source="gs://used_apartment/datasource/train.csv"
  )

  training_job_run_op = gcc_ai.CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp(
    project=PROJECT, display_name=display_name,
    container_uri="us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/dataops-rc2021/custom-train:latest",
    staging_bucket="vertex_ai_staging_rc2021",
    base_output_dir="gs://used_apartment/cstm_img_scrf/artifact",
    model_serving_container_image_uri="us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/dataops-rc2021/custom-pred:latest",
    model_serving_container_predict_route="/",
    model_serving_container_health_route="/health",
    model_serving_container_ports=[8080],
    training_fraction_split=0.8,
    validation_fraction_split=0.1,
    test_fraction_split=0.1,
    dataset=dataset_create_op.outputs["dataset"]
  )

def run_pipeline(event=None, context=None):
  # Compile the pipeline using the kfp.v2.compiler.Compiler
  compiler.Compiler().compile(
    pipeline_func=test_pipeline,
    package_path="test-pipeline.json"
  )

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run_pipeline()
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp component code. We were able to reproduce the error.

I have created the tracking bug  https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/5885.

Comment: Thank you! I will follow the status of this issue.